# Docker on Conemu

Tags: bash, conemu, docker, cmder

I am trying to make docker run on ConEmu by creating a task that open up Docker `start.sh` file using`git bash`.

Since normally docker Terminal is pointing to `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"` ,is there any way I can make a task on ConEmu to do this? So something like this:

[image]

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the task parameters:

```
/dir "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"
```

Commands:

```
"%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-quickstart-terminal.ico" "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

Please note that I have git in `Program Files (x86)`, and also that the `-new_console` parameter that references the ico is not needed. I assume you have that ico, but you can remove the whole parameter if it proves problematic, but you will be left with the Git bash icon.

Comment: so in my case, I needed to add `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox` to my path, too.

Comment: "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"%ProgramFiles%\Docker Toolbox\docker-quickstart-terminal.ico" "%ProgramFiles%\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"

Answer (score 9):

The posted answer didn't work for me (using Docker Toolbox 1.10.3). I chose to install Docker Bash shell during install (basically everything the installer offers).

Here's what worked for me (note the use of `bash.exe`):

**task parameters:**

```
/dir "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"
```

**Command:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-quickstart-terminal.ico" "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

Comment: accepted answer also didn't work for me, but this one worked. I'm using Docker Toolbox 1.11.0

Comment: This answer almost works for me, I can see the whale but I cannot use any `docker` command, I got **bash: docker.exe: command not found**, I don't know why, please advise.

Comment: This is my screenshot http://i.cubeupload.com/Hi7ETK.png

Comment: It looks similar to this issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17774. Feel free to open up another question if you need more help regrading this.

Answer (score 6):

Install docker before installing conEmu that is configured automatic.

[image]

Task Parameters:

`/dir "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%" /icon "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\docker.exe"`

Start console:

```
"%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\..\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe"-l -i "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\start.sh" -new_console:t:"Docker"
```

Comment: If ConEmu is installed before installing the docker toolbox, you can click "Add default tasks..." and it will repopulate the list and include Docker.

Comment: This is what worked for me. The other solutions kept complaining about the spaces in the directory paths and not being able to run "C:\Program"

Answer (score 1):

With ConEmu 160207 (on a Windows7 Pro), after installing Docker (version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe) and then bring up a ConEmu windows, I noticed there is a task for Docker automatically added.

Here's the ConEmu setting dialog box:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me for a freshly installed Docker Toolbox.

This is what I finally got to work.

Task Parameters

```
/dir "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%" /icon "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\docker.exe"
```

Commands

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\start.sh" -new_console:t:"Docker"
```